# Converter retorno ASCII Banco PostgreSQL para UTF-8 em Java Ksoap

Tags: java, android, codificação-de-caracteres

Tenho *app* Android que consome de um *webservice* onde o banco é PostgreSQL e o tipo  ASCII. Quando tento imprimir a *string* retornada no *app* ele desconfigura a letra com acentuação, por exemplo, `Pulmão = Pulm?o`.

Devo fazer esta conversão no serviço ou no cliente e qual o comando para o caso? E devo configurar alguma coisa na IDE Eclipse para que aceite este comando?

Exemplo:

1. O meu Webservice que é em java faz a consulta no banco postgres (ASCII) e retorna uma string/objeto com o campos. Estes campos são setados em um objeto do tipo pessoa por exemplo.
2. Este objeto é consumido pela aplicação Android para posterior visualização.
   Então se busco os dados da pessoa e veio o "João", o "ã" é impresso na tela desconfigurado. 
   O Eclipse está configurado para UTF-8, então não sei bem como tratar este problema. 
   Já tentei (getbytes().forname("UTF-8") e outros, mas da erro na sintaxe.

Trecho de retorno na aplicação:

```
HttpTransportSE Transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
Transport.debug = true;

Transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

//Recebendo retorno do Webservice

SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
```

Comment: Você poderia editar a pergunta com o seu método http?

Comment: Olá Wellington, a aplicação é em java. Editei a pergunta para ver se fica mais claro.

Comment: Veja se [isto](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16008621/3861347) te ajuda

Comment: Trabalho com o KSOAP2. Segue trecho do código de retorno na aplicação editado na pergunta.